# Split Multiple character in C#

Tags: c#

I want to split each words in this string?

I write a code

```
String s1=" welcome to our website,thanku."
string s2= s1.Split(",-.".ToArray());
```

But this isn't working.

Comment: BTW, it's more efficient to use `string.ToCharArray()` rather than `IEnumerable.ToArray()`

Comment: List (and maybe read) the compiler error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want to split on `space`, `,`,`.` and `-`, then try:

```
string[] splitArray = s1.Split(',','-','.',' ');
```

[string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) returns an array of string element, not a single string element.

Comment: don't forgert to remove empty entries.

Comment: @Arun, you are only missing space character from your string.

Comment: @Soner ..Nice..Working fine .. and Thanks To Habib once more

Comment: @habib Can I Put it in to a character array?? Like

string []S2= S1.Split("',','-','.',' '.ToCharArray());

Comment: @Arun, you don't have to, [`string.Split(char[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) is defined with `params` keyword. That will let you specify any number of characters for the split method.

Comment: @Arun, also ToCharArray is allowed with strings. If you are passing a string and want to split based on each character of string, like. `s1.Split(",-. ".ToCharArray());`

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a char[] to split function, char[] will hold all the character which will split the string.

```
string s2= s1.Split(",.- ".ToCharArray());
```

to ignore the empty string while splitting you can do it this way :

```
string s2= s1.Split(",.- ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOption.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: He is passing a char[] array (using `.ToArray()`)

Comment: I think the real issue is that the OP is not passing space character for splitting.

Answer (score 1):

It's nearly always helpful if one can say *how* something isn't working.

You can predefine your array of characters (for clarity):

```
var delimiters = new char[] { ',', '-' };
var results = string.Split(delimiters);
```

And then receive the result as an array (implicitly here), too.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String s1=" welcome to our website,thanku.";
string[] s2= s1.Split(new [] {",", "-", "."},  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```