# How to separate a string into different substrings without known format

Tags: c#, string

I am having trouble with this.
I have couple of strings like this [44, 74, 57]
Now I want to separate into 3 strings and omit the brackets and commas in C#, the output would be like this:

```
44
74
57
```

I have tried substring, concate, Regular expression but the problem is the strings, they don't have the same number of digits or format `[xx, yy, zz]`
Some strings are like `[44, 74, 57]`, others are like `[42, 6653, 40000]`

Can anyone help me what should I use?

Comment: is this an array in JSON?

Comment: @ParvSharma it just a string in C#, not an array

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split Multiple character in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15475401/split-multiple-character-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the `[]`'s and the `,`'s are strongly consistent the number of digits will be irrelevant and `Split` should work:

```
string tempstr = "[44, 74, 57]";
string[] outarray = tempstr.Split("[,] ".ToArray(),StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: the space character after each comma is still there.
the 3 outputs are `"44"`, `" 74"`, and `" 57"`

Comment: @HienTran - See my latest edit I added the space to the delimiter string.

Answer (score 1):

the string in your questions appears to be a JSON string. if this is the case then
use json deserialiser instead. One good options is `Newtonsoft.Json`

and you can have the numbers as an int array by using the command

```
var array JsonConvert.DesrializeObject<int[]>("[1,2,3]");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "[22, 4564, 65]";

string result[] = s.Replace('[', '').Replace(']', '').Split(',');
```

Comment: `tempstr.Replace('[', '').Replace(']', '').Split(',');`
I have error at the empty char.
It says `empty character literal`

Comment: try Replace('[', char.MinValue) @HienTran

Answer (score 0):

brute force regex `/\[(\d)+, ?(\d+), ?(\d+)\]/` data will be captured in groups 1, 2 and 3 cc: http://rubular.com/r/eheSoJFJ8q

Or using replace and split

```
char[] delimiterChars = { ', ', ',' };

string text = "[1, 2,333]";
string[] words = text.Replace('[','').Replace(']','').Split(comma);

System.Console.WriteLine("just the numbers {0}:", words);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        String s = "[11,12,23]";
        String[] s1 = s.Substring(1, s.Length - 2).Split(',');
```

s1 will have 3 arrays containing three numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
string tempstr = "[44, 74, 57]";
 tempstr=tempstr.Remove(']').Remove('[');
 string[] outarray =tempstr.Split(",");
```

Comment: What is the point of cloning the same answer multiple times? There are several similar answers already... All pointlessly creating extra strings with `.Remove` call.

Comment: Alexei Levenkov StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries you will dont get a extra string

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the brackets
Then split the string by comma.
You will end up with an array of the values you were expecting.

```
String value=[44,74,57,444,555];
Value=value.replace("[","");
Value=value.replace("]","");
String[] allValues=value.split(new char[]{','});
```

Now the array should contain all the values from your string.
That is mostly pseudo code. I wrote this on a tablet.
Hope it helps.

Comment: How this one is different from earlier once? (Except syntax errors and being "written on tablet", bot don't see to make answer much better)